# Finite atlas on a smooth manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If a smooth manifold admits a finite atlas, then for many technical purposes it is as good as compact. I was surprised to learn that every connected smooth manifold actually has a finite atlas. This result can be found in

A. Solecki. "Finite atlases on manifolds", Annales Societatis Mathematicae Polonae. Series I: Commentationes Mathematicae XVII (1974)

A Google search reveals only a few references to this paper in the whole net.

**Question:** Why is this result/paper so unpopular? Are there alternative proofs that are more popular/cited?

Please note that this question is very different from the existence of a finite covering atlas for a topological manifold. The atlas here has to be in the given smooth structure.

---

Theorem: For every smooth connected manifold $M^m$ of dimension m>1 there exists a finite atlas consisting of at most $2\cdot 3^{2m}$ full charts. The number of charts can be restricted to $3^{2m}$ if $\partial M=\emptyset$, to $2\cdot 3^m$ if $M$ is compact, and to $3^m$ is $M$ is compact and unbounded.

Comment: Wow, mathscinet doesn't list a single citation to this paper.

Comment: I think there is a topological bound on the number of charts required in Greub, Halperin and Van Stone. You might mention if Solecki has such a bound.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "for many technical purposes, it is as good as compact".  I don't know any applications of having a finite atlas.  It's also not a particularly hard result to prove; in fact, I've assigned it as a challenge problem when teaching smooth manifolds.  Of course, I don't have access to the paper in question, so I don't know what other properties the author establishes.

Comment: @BenMcKay I have cited the theorem now. Could you, please make your reference to Greub, Halperin and Van Stone more precise?

Comment: @AndyPutman why of course? You can Google the title to get access to the paper right away. That's how I got it in the first place. Also, having a finite atlas allows one to easily obtain many factorization properties of partial differential equations. What formulation exactly did you give as a problem that your topology students managed to prove?

Comment: The only pdf I could find with google was broken and my copy of acrobat couldn't open it.  Anyway, here is the problem I posed (I only asked for manifolds with boundary).  Let $M^n$ be a connected $n$-dimensional smooth manifold.

a. Prove that $M^n$ has an atlas consisting of $(n+1)$ charts $U \rightarrow V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where we allow $U$ to be disconnected.
b. Prove that you can ensure that the $U$ are connected.  Half credit for doing this with $n \geq 3$.

Comment: https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/960077.pdf

Comment: What about the Alexandroff line?

Comment: @JasonStarr: Don't most people require manifolds to be Hausdorff and second countable?  You certainly need at least second countable since Euclidean space is second countable.

Comment: @AndyPutman The $n+1$ result is about topological manifolds, that atlas is not smooth.

Comment: @Bedovlat: No, you can get $(n+1)$ for smooth manifolds too.  Here's a sketch.  Choose a smooth triangulation.  Let $U_0$ be the union of disjoint open neighborhoods of the vertices, each of which is diffeomorphic to a ball.  Next, let $U_1$ be the union of disjoint open neighborhoods of the result of deleting $U_0$ from the $1$-simplices, each of which is diffeomorphic to a ball.  Etc.  The result is an atlas $U_0,\ldots,U_n$ where each $U_i$ is the disjoint union of a bunch of open sets each of which is diffeomorphic to a ball and the union of $U_0,\ldots,U_k$ contains the (continued)

Comment: $k$-skeleton for each $0 \leq k \leq n$.  To fix this so that the $U_i$ are connected, tube the components together in a tree-like fashion.  This is easier if $n \geq 3$ since it is then easier to make sure that your tubes connecting components are disjoint.

An alternate approach is to use a smooth handle decomposition, which avoids some of the fiddling you need to make sure all the components are disjoint.  But my students only knew about triangulations!

Comment: (by the way, that's the link I found too, but somehow my copy of acrobat can't open it.  It claims the file is corrupted.)

Comment: @AndyPutman  Every smooth scheme over the field of complex numbers has an associated smooth complex analytic space.  This is what most people call the "associated complex manifold."  It need not be second countable and paracompact.  It need not be Hausdorff.  When I teach about complex manifolds, I do not assume that they are Hausdorff, second countable, paracompact.  I state the hypotheses that I need when I prove a theorem.

Comment: @JasonStarr: You're made of sterner stuff than me!  I'm more pro-algebraic geometry than most geometric topologists, but in my heart a smooth scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ is always separated and of finite type.  In any case, I personally always include Hausdorff and second countable whenever I teach manifolds, and I think that most books do too.

Comment: @AndyPutman What is, again, difficult for $n=2$? Looks perfectly fine to me. With a linear traingulation, connecting by lines can be done explicitly. For every fixed $k$ you first connect all of them by lines to get a complete graph, then enumerate the edges by induction according to their edge-distance from a vertex to get a weighted graph, then run Prim's algorithm to get a succession of subtrees. The union of subtrees will be a spanning tree. Now blow up the edges of the tree.

Comment: @AndyPutman This is not superfluous generality.  Many results in geometric invariant theory rely on foundational results applied to "big quotients" that are not Hausdorff, etc. (cf. Chapter 3, "An elementary example" in Mumford's "Geometric invariant theory").

Comment: @Bedovlat: I agree that something like that works for $n=2$.  For $n \geq 3$, you can do something even more trivial.  Let $\{B_i\}$ be a collection of disjoint open balls in $M^n$.  Pick some locally finite tree whose vertices are in bijection with the $B_k$.  For each edge $e$ in that tree connecting vertices corresponding to $B_i$ and $B_j$, let $\gamma_e$ be a path in $M^n$ connecting the boundaries of $B_i$ and $B_j$ that is disjoint from the union of all the $B_k$ (easy, since the $B_k$ cannot separate $M^n$).  Since $n \geq 3$, we can use transversality to assume (continued)

Comment: the $\gamma_e$ are all embedded and disjoint from each other.  Now thicken up the $\gamma_e$ to $1$-handles tubing the different $B_k$ together in the desired tree-like fashion.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thanks, I'll take a look at that chapter!